# Solving one variable in terms of the another

Tags: quadratics

Let $y = x^2 - 2x + 6$. Express $x$ in terms of $y$.

This is my working:

$$ x^2 - 2x = y - 6, \\
   x(x-2)= y - 6. $$

From this point, I got stuck as I can't fully factorize the $x$ out as seen above...

Thanks for the hint, if any...

Comment: [Complete the square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square): $x^2-2x=(x-1)^2-1$

Comment: For some values of $y$ there will be two solutions $x$, and for other values none.  Think "quadratic formula" (and possibly visualize the graph of this equation, as a parabola).

Answer (score 3):

$$y=x^2-2x+6$$
$$x^2-2x+(6-y)=0$$
Thus,
$$x=\frac{2\pm \sqrt{4-4(6-y)}}{2}$$
$$x={1\pm \sqrt{1-1(6-y)}}$$
$$x={1\pm \sqrt{y-5}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you complete the square. You have $x^2-2x+1=Y-5,$ so $(x-1)^2=Y-5,$ then $x-1=\pm \sqrt{Y-5}$ and add $1$ to each side.

Note there was an error before last edit.

Comment: Can I know why must we complete the square ? , thanks anyway for the help !